# Unable to share comments using ShareOpenGraphAction API in Development and Live mode for any user

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the Facebook app in my application. Our application will be live on tomorrow. I integrated the Facebook in developer mode. I am admin, I am able to post the message using ShareOpenGraphContent API. 
Below is my code :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
// On Successful Login share the story along with text and images
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareOpenGraphContent.class)) {
object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
.putString("fb:app_id", facebookAppId)
.putString("og:type", "books.book")
.putString("og:title", titleTxt)
.putString("og:description", descriptionTxt)
.putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
.build();
action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
.setActionType("books.reads")
.putPhotoArrayList("image", sharePhotoList)
.putObject("book", object)
.build();
}
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
.setPreviewPropertyName("book")
.setAction(action)
.build();
shareDialog.show(content);
}
}
```

Our requirement is any user which are having Facebook account must share the comment with story.Also these users are not present in the Role section list (Administrators, Developers,Testers, Insights Users ) of app id in development as well live mode.
I would thankful if anybody have the solution for the issue.

Comment: Dont you need publish_actions permission for that?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. publish_actions permission is working for below the Android M version. So is there any workaround solution available for the Android M version.